# How to convert less mixin to scss?

Tags: sass, less

I only just starting to learn both less and sass and can't figure out how to convert this less mixin to scss. This one compiles just fine and provides proper values in a compiled .css file:

```
.button-styles(@type) {
    &--@{type} {
        border-color: @@type;
        a:hover {
            background: @@type;
            color: #FFF;
        }
    }
}
```

I tried using different converters.

This doesn't work, for example:

```
@mixin button-styles($type){
    &--${type} {
        border-color: $$type;
        a:hover {
            background: $$type;
            color: #FFF;
        }
    }
}
```

I also tried to tinker with this mixin myself but I can't make it to work.

Help, please.